# Unable to dual boot windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8

I can boot into either Ubuntu or Windows by manually selecting them from the BIOS and I boot with no trouble into Ubuntu from GRUB but when I select "Windows 8" from GRUB I am greeted with the following:

> can't find command 'drivemap'
>   invalid EFI file path

My basic setup:

Rampage IV Motherboard
3x SSD (1 for windows, 1 for scratch space, 1 for Ubuntu)

Windows was installed first
Ubuntu was installed second

I already tried running boot-repair twice, once from installed Ubuntu, once from a live usb.  The output of boot-repair:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/1577730/

Any suggestions on how to get dual-boot working?  I think I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Duplicate thread. Please search the archives before posting! 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8/235519#235519

Answer (score 0):

in that case you need a clean installation of windows 8 and then make a partition for ubuntu i suggest to download and install wubi (wubi can determine if your computer is 32 bit or 64 bit) and then install it to the another partition .