# How can I boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 on a PC with an EFI bootloader?

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi

I just bought a Lenovo ideaPad Z400. I installed the ubuntu 13.04 without problem. Now, I cna't boot the windows 8. Eaither in secure boot mode enabled or disabled. I am frustrated.  this is my boot-repair auto generated file. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5645521/

In the grub boot menu, there are several options, Windows 8 loader, WIndows 8 recovery UEFi. I can get into windows 8 with recovery UEFI. However, the regular windows 8 doesn't work. And I don't know what's the difference between these two windows mode and if there is any solution to solve.

If I load regular windows 8, it tells me no drivemap command found, and invalid efi ...

Comment: There seems to be problems with newer laptops that come with preinstalled Windows 8 and  EFI bootloaders. GRUB2 doesn't seem to do the job. Looking forward to see the answer.

Comment: This [post on AskUbuntu.com][1] seems to tackle your problem. 

[1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8

Comment: It seems to work, however, I am not familiar with the ESP. So I haven't tried yet. Is my ESP gpt2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the GRUB option called "Windows UEFI recovery bkpbootmgfw.efi" *does* boot Windows, but you've got additional GRUB entries that don't work. If so, that's working the way it's supposed to work -- or at least, the way the Boot Repair tool is supposed to set things up. (It's not a very good solution, and I have more to say on the subject on [my Web page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/bootrepair.html). This is a problem with labels and with having too many options, not with an inability to boot Windows. If I understand correctly, the simplest solution is to ignore the issue and just use the awkwardly-named Windows boot option. There are several other options, though. Two that are relatively easy are:

- Use a tool called [GRUB 2 Customizer](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/grub-customizer-20-can-change-default.html) to adjust the GRUB menu entries. I've never used this tool, though, so I can't provide further guidance on it.
- Re-run the Boot Repair tool, click Advanced Options, click Restore EFI Backups, and click Apply. After doing this, install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) This often does a better job launching Windows than GRUB does; however, it may have an extra boot option or two that you'll want to get rid of using rEFInd's own methods -- either deleting the offending files or using the `dont_scan_dirs` or `dont_scan_files` options in `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf`.

If I've completely misunderstood your post and you can't boot Windows from GRUB, then the first of these solutions won't do you any good -- at least, not without better understanding the problem and having a replacement GRUB boot stanza for Windows. The second solution might work, but if I've misunderstood, I recommend you post a clarification and wait for further responses before proceeding.

Comment: Windows UEFI recovery bkpbootmgfw.efi doesn't boot normally, it boots the recovery system, which if I proceed, will covert the laptop to a clean installed.