# Windows 8 doesn't boot after installing Ubuntu (UEFI)

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.04, windows-8, uefi

I installed Ubuntu with my UEFI installation of Windows 8 (with windows 7 boot-loader because I don't know how to recover it), and after grub installed, I was no longer able to boot Windows 8.
I tried with several different tutorials, which resulted in the two menu entries called 'Windows 7' that you'll see in the pastebin output.

I also disabled fastBoot.  It's my first time with Linux so this is a bit difficult for me to solve, and the existing answers seem incomplete.

Output from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5656809/

Comment: That question doesn't have an accepted answer. [This one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/292692/how-can-i-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-13-04-on-a-pc-with-an-efi-bootloader) does, although I don't think the poster of that question is entirely happy with the answer. My answer to this question is similar to my answer to the one to which I've linked, although only my second bulleted option would apply in this case. Also, I recommend that Uriel disable Secure Boot if it's currently enabled. That's far more important than disabling Fast Boot.

Comment: @Uriel did you try http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restore Windows 8.1.1 to the boot menu after restoring the MBR. I booted from a live USB with Boot-Repair-Disk on it, used Gparted to check the disks, then somehow found a way (I don't remember the actions, for which I apologize) to boot into Windows. I then used EasyBCD to make Windows the default option and rebooted, which restored the MBR boot menu with Windows at the default option and Ubuntu listed as the second option.

I think the app that actually helped me RESTORE THE MBR was Grub Customizer.