# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8, and W8 won't boot anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, system-installation

I've bought a Dell laptop with W8 pre-installed. I didn't like W8 much, so I wanted to try Ubuntu, but without uninstalling W8. So yesterday I installed Ubuntu, and it was extremely convoluted thanks to the gorgeous W8 UEFI boot mode.

Anyway Ubuntu is now installed and working with no problem. However I cannot boot on W8 anymore, which is a serious issue.

I tried Boot repair, first with the boot option in Legacy mode, then in UEFI. Boot repair tells me it got it fixed, but I still can't boot on W8.

When I boot, I have two options to boot on Windows: *Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi*
and *Windows Boot UEFI loader*.

When I select any of them, I got the following error:

```
No such device BCE6-E3C4
/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi not found.
```

**OR**

```
No such device BCE6-E3C4
/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi not found.
```

I checked on my computer, and unexpectedly, I **did** find the two files, located at `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi` or `/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi`.

My computer has 2 hard drives. When I got the computer, the second one was empty, so I decided I'd install Ubuntu on my second hard drive, and keep W8 on my first one. Maybe that's the problem, maybe the bios or whatever it is is looking in the first hard drive for the efi files, while they are supposedly in the second one.

I've tried lots of stuff on the Internet (like updating grub's config) but nothing's worked so far.

Boot repair told me to paste this link if I need help, so here we go: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5789091/

I read but that didn't help me much.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I can still access to my data on my first hard drive, but I still have many useful programs on Windows. I notably program in C++ for Windows, so I must, in order to compile for the OS, boot on Windows.

Comment: You can try this link :  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/292692/how-can-i-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-13-04-on-a-pc-with-an-efi-bootloader?rq=1

Comment: Try changing your default boot device to your other hard drive, that works in my W8 box with UEFI firmware.  Doesn't solve the grub trouble, but it may let you back into windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04 on a PC with an EFI bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292692/how-can-i-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-13-04-on-a-pc-with-an-efi-bootloader)

Answer (score 3):

That's it! I've been able to boot on Windows 8 again ! The second link given in the comments by SimplySimon was extremely useful. I've installed [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and it does the job perfectly.

For future readers having the same issue, rEFind manager is a new boot utility that allows you to choose from your installed OS when you start your computer. I chose Windows, and it simply worked (even with fast start-up option on). And I restarted and chose Ubuntu, and it worked fine too.

Thanks again.