# How do I uninstall ubuntu (installed alongside Windows 8)?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, windows-8

Looking for a detailed how-to on uninstalling Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. I've installed it alongside Windows 8.

Comment: Hi welcome to askubuntu! Could you please edit your question to tell us whether you used the Wubi installer from inside windows or the installer from the live usb stick and chose 'install alongside Windows'.

Comment: Are you using UEFI? To check it, open a shell and type `efibootmgr`. It is very impoprtant.

Answer (score 1):

If using old BIOS with MBR, delete the Ubuntu partition from Windows 8 Computer Managment, and reinstall the MBR boot code. To restore the default Windows 8 MBR Code, google for `fixmbr` or `bcdedit` (Boot Configuration Data).

If using UEFI with GPT, delete the Ubuntu partition from Windows 8 Computer Managment, and use `bcdedit` (Boot Configuration Data) to alter the UEFI System Variable.
[here is a question that I asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8/235519#235519)

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx