# GRUB menu does not show Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I just installed Ubuntu next to my Windows 10 installation. However, the GRUB menu only gives me the option to boot Ubuntu and does not show any option for Windows.

**What I have tried so far:**

- I made sure that both are installed in UEFI mode
- Running `sudo os-prober` gives me the following:

  `/dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi`
- Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows) I added the following to my `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {  
     insmod ntfs  
     set root='(hd0,1)'  
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 7EB1-5748
     chainloader +1  
}
```

But when I select this option from the GRUB menu I receive this error message:

```
error: invalid EFI file path.
```

What else can I do allowing me to choose between Ubuntu and Windows from the GRUB menu?

Comment: Boot Windows directly in UEFI, install any pending updates, disable Fast Startup, a MUST when dual-booting, and shutdown. Change the boot order back to Ubuntu and run os-prober again.

Comment: You need an UEFI boot stanza for Windows. Like: https://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8-grub-error-cant-find-command