# I have dual boot. Each opreating system has its own drive. How to swich between them without going to bios?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bios

I have installed windows 11 on my hard drive and Ubuntu in my SSD. The question is how can I switch between them without going to bios.

Comment: Are both installed in UEFI boot mode? Is Windows fast startup & bitlocker off? If so then you can boot from grub menu. You may need to run `sudo update-grub` if os-prober set to true in grub. Or manually add boot stanza to boot Windows UEFI entry in 40_custom. Older, but custom entry for UEFI Windows is still the same: https://askubuntu.com/questions/233687/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-along-windows-8-grub-error-cant-find-command

Comment: I installed Grub customize form PPA. and solve it. Thank you